# What happen with bounty in following case?

Tags: support, bounties

I am going to start bounty for a my question. If no one will answer my question, what happens to that bounty?

Comment: It will just expire.

Comment: It is collected by the system as payment for allowing your question to be displayed in the "Featured" tab for a week.

Comment: If there is no user to award it to, it will be used by the employees of SE to buy their ice cream at the ice cream van.

Comment: @Bart what's the current exchange rate from SER (StackExchange Reputation) to USD?

Comment: @CodyGray I find it weird how we think it's ok to pay computers to do things. They're dumb. They don't know how to do things unless told how, so why do we find it ok to pay them to do something?

Comment: You aren't paying the *computer* to do it, @Cole. You're paying for a service: listing your question on the "Featured" tab so you get more views. The fact that the service is provided by a computer through code is irrelevant. Err, and, the fact that they are imaginary points...

Comment: @CodyGray wait!? Reputation isn't real!? What's next!? Unicorns don't exist!? Skeet is a human!? I don't know what to do with myself anymore.

Comment: No, [unicorns definitely exist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/137537/boltclocks-a-unicorn).

Comment: @CodyGray ok, now I feel _a little_ better.

Answer (score 0):

Once started, you lose the rep and isn't refunded back.